# Can not show "detail form" in next page pagination datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

when I click `class="detail"` button, `detail-form` will show perfectly, but after i click datatable paging to next page (next record of datatable), `detail-form` not show. I try to change datatables configuration to `"paging": false`, it work. How to do this without change `"paging"` datatables configuration?

This my table

```
<div id="detail-form">
.................
</div>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>NIM</th>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach($maha as $m): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$no++?></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="<?=$m->id?>" class="detail"><?=$m->username?></td>
        <td><?=$m->nomor?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;
    ?>
</table>
```

And my script

```
$(function () {
$("#table").DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "scrollX": true,
});)};

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".detail").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $("#detail-form").show("slow");
...............................
```

Answer (score 0):

> class="detail">username?>

close tag A

> $(".detail").each(function(){
>
> $(this).click(function(){

suggestion to use jquery on

$(target).on(action,function(){

});